# How to replace an element of an alist?

Tags: elisp, association-lists

I have this by default in my `auto-mode-alist`:

```
("\\.js\\'" . javascript-mode)
```

(even with `emacs -Q`).  I'd like to substitute `js2-mode` for `javascript-mode`.  Of course, I could use `assq-delete-all` and then `add-to-list` again, but I'm wondering whether there isn't a better way.

Edit: I explicitly *do not want* to use Customize, I prefer crafting my `init.el` myself.

Answer (score 58):

While @Dan's answer is a perfectly fine solution, it is unnecessary. One of the reasons Emacs uses an ***alist*** here is that with an alist you can simply add a new element to the front of the list and it will *shadow matches further down the list*.

```el
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))
```

Comment: Admittedly, it does not answer the question of how to **replace**. Its point is that you **do not need** to replace (unless you have some other need than what you described).

Comment: Exactly.  Still, in my book this counts as a solution (even if I do not like it).

Comment: +1. It's the less-convoluted solution for working with this alist than the `setf` option, but the latter gets to the question of how to *replace* elements rather than shadow them.

Comment: the question wasn't *really* about replacing in the technical sense but rather changing in the higher-level sense.

Comment: This will always work no matter if the cons is in pure space or will be removed in some future version.

Answer (score 55):

Use [`setf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Generalized-Variables.html) to change the value in place:

```
(setf (cdr (rassoc 'javascript-mode auto-mode-alist)) 'js2-mode)
```

If you want to *replace* a value in the list, then `setf` is the generalized machinery you need to do so.  For the more idiomatic way to deal with the `auto-mode-alist`, see @Drew's answer (and his explanation of shadowing).

Comment: @mbork You might enjoy this classic explanation to the Perl guys.  http://lists.warhead.org.uk/pipermail/iwe/2005-July/000130.html

Answer (score 27):

The fastest way to actually change the cons cell is probably `setcdr`

```
setcdr is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(setcdr CELL NEWCDR)

Set the cdr of CELL to be NEWCDR.  Returns NEWCDR.
```

It's worth noting that `setf` isn't available in older Emacsen, but `setcdr` is.

---

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (setq tmp '((one . 1) (two . 2) (three . 4)))
((one . 1)
 (two . 2)
 (three . 4))

ELISP> (setcdr (assq 'three tmp) 3)
3 (#o3, #x3, ?\C-c)
ELISP> tmp
((one . 1)
 (two . 2)
 (three . 3))
```

Comment: Do you happen to know which version of Emacs added `setf`?

Comment: @dsheperd not off-hand, no. Why do you need to know? I would say any emacs that should be targeted for new development will have setf, but there might not be handling for it for the kind of data you want to set. They're called [generalized variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Generalized-Variables.html).

Comment: I wanted to know if it was ok to use setf in some new code, but as you said it turns out there was no generalised variable for what I wanted until too recent a version anyway.

Answer (score 14):

The OP asks for a solution which handles alists that have string keys. To handle that, see [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/33892/12534). If by chance you only need to handle alists with symbol keys, then as of Emacs 25 you can use:

```
(setf (alist-get <key> <alist>) <value>)
```

to replace a cdr. If you have access to Emacs 26, this technique does work with string keys, as follows:

```
(setf (alist-get "\\.js\\'" auto-mode-alist nil nil #'equal) 'js2-mode)
```

Note that there are also other ways in Emacs 26 to handle string keys; see [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/33892/12534) as mentioned above.

Comment: `(setf (alist-get "\\.js\\'" auto-mode-alist nil nil #'equal) 'js2-mode)` should work (requires Emacs 26 though).

Comment: @RadonRosborough: there is an edit feature. Consider to fix you answer.

Comment: You are using `alist-get` with the string `"\\.js\\'"`, but 
`alist-get` is based on `assq`, so it won't work with a string as you claim in your answer.

Comment: @antonio Oh yes, you are entirely correct. I had not realized that the question as posted actually does require a solution which handles string keys. I'll make the edit, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you know you won't use javascript-mode ever again let auto-mode-alist untouched and add to your init.el

```
  (defalias 'javascript-mode 'js2-mode "Some handy explanation goes here.")
```

Comment: Actually, there is no `javascript-mode`, really:  `javascript-mode` is only an alias for `js-mode` (by default) and it was done this way *specifically* so that users could do like you suggest if they prefer `js2-mode` (without losing the ability to use `js-mode` if they want to).

Comment: I derived my answer from habit of aliasing for cperl-mode and nxml-mode. So what would do the trick here? (defalias 'js-mode 'js2-mode)?

Comment: You misunderstood me.  I'm saying that your answer is exactly right and doesn't prevent you from using "javascript-mode" since what you call by that name is really `js-mode` (contrary to what happens for `perl-mode`, for instance).

Comment: Got it... (casual javascript-mode user here)

Answer (score 1):

With the new `seq.el` library you can filter the alist.

E.g. we can `seq-filter` the `auto-mode-alist`.
We return `nil` for the entries we wish to remove from the alist and `t` for the entries we want to stay.

```lisp
(seq-filter
 (lambda (x)
   (if (equal (car x) "\\.js\\'")
       nil
     t))
auto-mode-alist)
```

Then you set the `auto-mode-alist` value to this new filtered alist.

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist (seq-filter
 (lambda (x)
   (if (equal (car x) "\\.js\\'")
       nil
     t)) auto-mode-alist))
```

**Edit:** Drew simplified the predicate in the comments:

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist 
  (seq-filter
    (lambda (x)
      (not (equal (car x) "\\.js\\'"))) 
    auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: Aka `(not (equal (car x) "\\.js\\'"))`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that is simpler.