# Looking for a simple way to update an alist without introducing degeneracies

Tags: association-lists

In my `.emacs` file I have code like this:

```
(setq default-frame-alist
      (assq-delete-all 'width default-frame-alist))

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             (cons 'width new-width))
```

The first expression ensures that the second one does not introduce a "degenerate key" in the alist (IOW, multiple elements having the same `car`).

That's a *javaesque* amount of machinery for what other languages achieve with something that looks very similar to this:

```
default_frame_list["width"] = new_width
```

Is there a simpler way?

PS: Of course, one could reply with "just get rid of the first expression" (IOW, "don't worry about degenerate keys"), but this does not answer my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace an element of an alist?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/how-to-replace-an-element-of-an-alist/3398#3398).  Short version: use `setf` if you want to update the list in place, but the idiomatic way is to push a new value onto the front of the list.  That new value shadows the later values, which are effectively ignored.

Answer (score 12):

In Emacs-25, there's `alist-get` which you can use to get *and* set a key.  E.g. you can do what you want with:

```
(setf (alist-get 'width default-frame-alist) new-width)
```

Comment: If it's the same `alist-get` given [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/subr.el), I don't see where the key is set...

Comment: The setter is in gv.el.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if your alist keys are strings. For a solution that does, see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/33893/12534.

Comment: Indeed, I'm beginning to think it was a mistake to use `assq` instead of `assoc` in the definition of `alist-get`.

Answer (score 5):

First off, if you think that your alist has duplicate keys (which you call 'degenerate') and you want to remove them then you will have to call `assq-delete-all` or something like that.

As to how to set the value without creating duplicate keys (since the simplest way to deal with an alist is to just cons on a new cons pair to the front) you will need to use something like `setf`.

There are a few functions you can use, they are all similar and effectively do the same thing. They set the *value* of a *place*. A place is something like a `car` or a `cdr` of a list.

You can use `setcdr` (or its alias `rplacd`) to set the value of the cdr of the cons cell returned by `assq` to the new value:

```
(rplacd (assq 'width default-frame-alist) new-width)
```

Or you can use `setf` to do the same thing:

```
(setf (cdr (assq 'width default-frame-alist) new-width)
```

`setf` is more general and works by looking up `setf methods` defined for the *place* (i.e. `car` or `cdr` or `first`) and then calling that function with the other parameters. There are even ways for one to define one's own `setf methods`.

For reference look up [Generalized Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generalized-Variables.html#Generalized-Variables) in the Elisp manual.

Comment: (defun update-alist-tag (tag val alist)
  (nconc
   (list (cons tag val))
   (assq-delete-all tag alist)))

Comment: That could work as well. I currently prefer the setf form myself.

Comment: This doesn't work if `alist` doesn't contain the `key` already.

Comment: @politza ouch! you are correct. I'll have to dig into the manual to see if there is a consise way around that. I think though the idiom of consing a new pair onto the alist is *the* way to do it - but outside of the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old alist.el library from the Emacs vs XEmacs days - someone added it to their .emacs folder so you can browse it - https://github.com/baron/emacs/blob/master/.emacs.d/el-get/apel/alist.el. It would let you say

```
(set-alist 'default-frame-alist 'width 80)
```

It's not namespaced to 'alist-' though, and not orthogonal - eg it has (put-alist KEY VALUE ALIST) vs (set-alist SYMBOL KEY VALUE), so it could use a little updating.