# Replace element of alist using `equal` even if key does not exist

Tags: association-lists

I have an alist whose keys are strings, and I need to set the value for one of its keys. If the key is not present, I need to add it. So for example,

```
(alist-set "a" "bb" '(("a" . "b") ("c" . "d"))) => '(("a" . "bb") ("c" . "d"))
(alist-set "a" "bb" '(("c" . "d"))) => '(("a" . "bb") ("c" . "d"))
```

Introducing duplicate entries is not acceptable. Mutating the original alist is allowed.

Here are some incorrect solutions:

- Using `alist-get`:

  ```
   (setf (alist-get key alist) val)
  ```

  This is incorrect because `alist-get` compares keys using `eq`, but string keys must be compared using `equal`. I could implement a new version of the `setf` accessor for `alist-get` that uses `equal`, but the original implementation in `gv.el` is 26 lines of code. That is a lot of boilerplate for this simple operation.
- Using `setcdr` with `assoc`:

  ```
  (setcdr (assoc key alist) val)
  (setf (cdr (assoc key alist)) val)
  ```

  This is incorrect because it fails when the key is not present in the alist to begin with.
- Use the fact that earlier entries in an alist shadow later ones:

  ```
  (push (cons key val) alist)
  ```

  This is incorrect because it introduces a duplicate entry for `key` in the alist.

Here are some questions whose answers do not answer this question:

- [Looking for a simple way to update an alist without introducing degeneracies](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9328/12534)
- [How to replace an element of an alist?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3397/12534)

Comment: One wonders *why* you are using an alist if "*introducing duplicate entries is not acceptable*". Why not use some other representation (e.g. a hash list)? Is it because you have no control over the source data and you don't want to create another representation for it?

Comment: Please consider filing an enhancement request for `alist-get` to accept an optional `TEST` parameter, which provides the comparison predicate to use. Alists with string keys are common. Seems like an oversight that `alist-get` hard-codes `eq`.

Comment: @Drew I am writing a package manager, and one of its functions is recording the commits of each package repository, and writing them to a lockfile. Writing them as an alist is pretty and makes for elegant diffs, as well as being human-readable/writable. Using a hash table would not be as nice.

Comment: @Drew I would file an enhancement request, but the Emacs community does not currently make it easy to do so, and I do not currently have the time to figure out the process. If someone else wishes to, I think it's a great idea.

Comment: It as simple as  `M-x report-emacs-bug RET`.

Comment: @politza You're right, of course. I was thinking of emacs-devel, which is not nearly as pleasant. The point is moot, however, since apparently the functionality has already been added in Emacs trunk: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34227/12534

Comment: Yes, arguing its necessity would have been a whole different thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Emacs version 26.1, `alist-get`
accepts an optional argument **testfn**; when this argument is
non-nil, then `alist-get` uses it to compare the keys instead of
**eq**.

Then you can do:

```
(let ((alist (list (cons "a" "b") (cons "c" "d"))))
  (setf (alist-get "a" alist nil nil 'equal) "bb")
  alist)
=> (("a" . "bb") ("c" . "d"))
```

Another way is to use the builtin library **map.el**.  This library
adds an abstration layer to handle uniformly hash-tables, alists
and arrays.  This has the advantage that if you later decide to
use a hash-table instead of an alist, your code using **map.el**
remains valid.

With **map.el** you'd write:

```
(require 'map)
(let ((map (list (cons "a" "b") (cons "c" "d"))))
  (map-put map "a" "bb" 'equal)
  map)
=> (("a" . "bb") ("c" . "d"))
```

Comment: This is great! I had never seen **map.el** before. It should be noted that this library is also recent, having been added in 25.1. http://endlessparentheses.com/new-in-emacs-25-1-map-el-library.html

Comment: Plot twist: the `TESTFN` argument to `map-put` was only added in Emacs 26.1 as well. Thus, I'm unaccepting this answer until Emacs 26.1 comes out.

Comment: @RadonRosborough, Emacs 26.1 is out ;-)! I think you may accept this answer now.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution, which does not require traversing the
alist twice, and satisfies all of my other conditions.

```
(defun alist-set (key val alist &optional symbol)
  "Set property KEY to VAL in ALIST. Return new alist.
This creates the association if it is missing, and otherwise sets
the cdr of the first matching association in the list. It does
not create duplicate associations. By default, key comparison is
done with `equal'. However, if SYMBOL is non-nil, then `eq' is
used instead.

This method may mutate the original alist, but you still need to
use the return value of this method instead of the original
alist, to ensure correct results."
  (if-let ((pair (if symbol (assq key alist) (assoc key alist))))
      (setcdr pair val)
    (push (cons key val) alist))
  alist)
```

You will need to include

```
(require 'subr-x)
```

in order to have access to `if-let`.

Comment: You can use instead`(eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))` because **if-let** is a macro.