# "Dissasociate" auto-mode for specific files (in ESS)

Tags: use-package, ess, association-lists, auto-mode-alist

I'd like to keep `ess` as automatic major mode for R files and everything else, except for Julia, for which I want to use `julia-mode` alone.  However, I cannot find out how to "unbind" the [file association of `ess-julia-mode`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/9329b410bec2004ec6199bb5070f2072f5b18330/lisp/ess-julia.el#L439).

Without really knowing what I do, I tried putting

```
 (setq auto-mode-alist (assq-delete-all "\\.jl\\'" auto-mode-alist))
```

at some places, but it had no effect.  My package loading is essentially the following (in this order):

```
(use-package ess
  :init (require 'ess-site)) ;; adds association automatically

(use-package julia-mode
  :mode "\\.jl\\'")          ;; set association manually - no effect
```

How can I make sure that `.jl` files use `julia-mode`, while keeping the other associations from `ess`?

(I use `use-package` for package loading; but any answer dealing with the same problem in general is equally welcome.  It might also be independent of `ess`.)

Comment: Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/how-to-replace-an-element-of-an-alist (not sure if it should count as dup, due to the autoloading subtleties).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is mostly caused by autoloads.

In [julia-mode.el](https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-emacs/blob/2ef6992125a85674532a1e37dacd5c60bee4feeb/julia-mode.el#L66) you can see that `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode))` is marked as to be autoloaded. If you were to look at `~/.emacs.d/elpa/julia-mode-${version}/julia-mode-autoloads.el` (which is automatically generated from `julia-mode.el` when you initially install the package), you would indeed see that line.

Crucially, the `-autoloads.el` files in all the `elpa/xx/` subdirectories are, themselves, loaded automatically<sup>†</sup> and at the very beginning of start-up — their purpose is to defer loading of the "real" files until they're necessary, but in order for that to be possible, they have to be loaded at start-up). Indeed, if you were to comment out your entire init-file, but without deleting any of the installed packages, `auto-mode-alist` would still contain `("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode)`.

† well, [unless you set `package-enable-at-startup` to `nil`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html#index-package_002denable_002dat_002dstartup-4595)

In contrast, `ess-autoloads.el` only adds `'("\\.R$" . R-mode)` to the auto-mode-alist ([see here](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/9329b410bec2004ec6199bb5070f2072f5b18330/ess-autoloads.el#L59) — yes, in the case of `ess`, the autoloads file is present at the source, rather than being generated at installation, but that doesn't really matter). The `.jl` association is, as you noted, only added in `ess-julia.el`.

`add-to-list` adds the given element to the top of the list, but only if it's not already present (see the docstring of the function). Hence, the order of operations regarding the `.jl` association is:

1. `("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode)` is added from `julia-mode-autoloads.el`
2. When you `(require 'ess-site)`, which in turn [`require`s `ess-julia.el`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/9329b410bec2004ec6199bb5070f2072f5b18330/lisp/ess-site.el#L123), `auto-mode-alist` has `("\\.jl\\'" . ess-julia-mode)` added to its beginning, effectively "overriding"<sup>‡</sup> `("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode)`
3. `:mode "\\.jl\\'"` expands to `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode))`, but since `("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode)` is already an element of `auto-mode-alist`, it does nothing.

‡ when opening a file, parsing of `auto-mode-alist` is in order, and (sort-of) stops when you find a match, so later occurrences of the same pattern have no effect

### Hack-ish solution

Change the use-package block dedicated to `julia-mode`:

```
(use-package julia-mode
  :init
  (push '("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode) auto-mode-alist)
  (delete-dups auto-mode-alist))
```

`push`, unlike `add-to-list` does not try to be clever and just adds the element to the beginning of the list. `delete-dups` removes duplicates, leaving the first occurrence (it's not strictly necessary, but I've added it for neatness's sake). As a result, `("\\.jl\\'" . julia-mode)` is now before `("\\.jl\\'" . ess-julia-mode)`.

### Why does `assq-delete-all` not work?

`assq-delete-all` uses `eq` rather than `equal` for comparison (see the docstring), but `eq` does not work in the "expected" way for string — e.g. `(eq "a" "a")` evaluates to nil.

Comment: The hack does everything I want, thanks! After reading your explanation, I also tried `use-package`s `:after` command (`:after julia-mode` in the `ess` part), but that had the disadvantage of still overwriting the setting after `ess` has been loaded once...